# Store a file on IPFS

Tags: ipfs

I have tried to install an ipfs node on my computer.

It works: I have stored files and i can get them with their hash.

Now, what i want to do is to "publish" my files to the "full network".

I want to access my files from this kind of url:

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/<myhash>
```

How can i do that ?

What is ipfs.io ? Is it a node ? Is it something centralized ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ipfs is a new generation of web technology. it remove s the drawback of http based seacrh request with unique fingerprint called CID . this is a cryptographic hash of your file . in short this is  a type of blockchain based file storage system so it is decentralized network no one can alter data stored in ipfs